# Left R-module structure on tensor product with ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If $R$ is a ring with unit and $M$ a left R-module, in which way becomes $R\underset{R}{\otimes}M$  a left R-module? Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the other negative solution. I can't believe what I wrote in the first pass, or that it got votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have an $S,R$ bimodule $N$, the abelian group $N\otimes_RM$ has a natural left $S$ module structure given by

$s(n\otimes m):=sn\otimes m$.

The ring is an $R,R$ bimodule over itself, so this is possible.

And the other obvious thing holds, that if $M$ is additionally an $R,T$ bimodule, then $N\otimes_R M$ has an $S, T$ bimodule structure given in the obvious way.

Comment: Is the first statement also true if $N$ is only a left $S$ module and a right $R$ module but not a $S$,$R$ bimodule?

Comment: @aii I can't verify why in my head, but I don't think that is enough. In all books I have seen anyway, they stick to bimodules

Answer (score 0):

> We have a theorem: if $R,S$ rings,
>
> $1)$ if $_SM_R $  a left $S$-  module , a right $R$-  module and $_RN$ a left $R$-  module then  $M \otimes_R N$ a left $S$- module.
>
> $2)$ if $M_R $ a right $R$-  module and $_RN_S$ a left $R$-  module , right $S$-  module then $M \otimes_R N$ a right $S$- module.

in your question:  $R\otimes_R  M  $ a left $R$- module if $M$ a left $R$- module.
and in a partical we have $R\otimes_R M \cong M$